# how process static file when deploying django using docker and aws eb

Tags: django, docker, deployment

I used Django, Docker and AWS Elastic Beanstalk to employ my website. I followed the instruction of https://github.com/glynjackson/django-docker-template.
I met problem when I try to load static file, the browser try to visit mysite.com/static/css/xx.css to get the css and javascipt file which is different with what I run it locally.
In settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

I also used:

```
# !/bin/sh
cd /var/projects/mysite && python manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

Currently, I write additional views and urls for javascript and css file. So browser can get these file from url. But how to do it correctly?

Comment: i used 'load static' in index.html                                         {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/css/style.css' %}">

Comment: If you are using AWS, best to release static files on S3 or cloudfront. You can use django-storages

Comment: Beanstalk has actually a simple way of hosting your static for you. All you need to do is to introduce your static folder location in the configuration page. I would argue that it's the best option.